# How do I move a file to the trash with LaunchBar?

Tags: mac

How do I use LaunchBar to move a file to the trash?

I've tried (after selecting the file in LaunchBar) pressing TAB (for Send to…), but then I can't figure out how to specify the trash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you would in the Finder ... Cmd-delete